# Can I represent a computer program on a Hilbert Curve?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, knowledge-representation

I overheard in discussion tonight:

> You know - you can represent a computer program as points on a Hilbert Curve.

Is there a reference that explains this concept? I can't seem to Google for it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Hilbert Curve reference, but since the Hilbert Curve is continuous and space-filling it's equivalent to representing a program as a point in the unit square. You can just as easily represent a computer program as a real number between (0,1) by transforming the program into binary, concatenating the digits, and prepending a $0.$

Comment: That would be a rational number, to be more precise. Of course, why not just use a natural number? (I'd say the question is too vague.)